# python decorated function with multiple args (Tornado)

Tags: python, arguments, decorator, tornado

I have written a decorator to authenticate calls. It works fine with only one argument, but with more it doesn't, triggering off a `inner() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. I have a bit of a callback spaghetti since I'm using Tornado, but I'm not sure what's the best way to do this.

```
#this works
class FirstHandler(BaseHandler):

    @asynchronous
    @oauth_machine.auth
    def post(self):
        print self.user
        self.finish()

#this now also does
class SecondHandler(BaseHandler):

    @asynchronous
    @oauth_machine.auth
    def get(self, args):
        self.write("ok")
        self.finish()
```

The decorator function(s)

```
def auth(fn):
    def inner(self, *args):
        res = get_user_by_credentials(self, fn, args, callback=done_auth)
    return inner

def get_user_by_credentials(self, fn, callback):

    def onFetchUserCredentials(result, error):
        self.user = result
        callback(self, fn, args)

    email = self.get_argument("email")
    password = self.get_argument("password")
    settings.DB.users.find_one({'email': email, 'password': password }, callback=onFetchUserCredentials)

def done_auth(result, fn, args):
    return fn(result, args)
```

EDIT :

Updated code to working version.

Thanks!

Comment: Change `def inner(self):` to `def inner(*args):` and `print args` to see what arguments are being passed in.

Comment: I get the two args passed in the function. By changing `self` to `args[0]`, I still get a `get() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`. Where am I not passing the second argument?

Comment: You don't have any code that's calling `get`. Assuming you've posted all of the relevant code, that means it's something inside Tornado that's calling your `get` improperly, which probably means you're calling something in Tornado improperly. Post the stack trace so we can see.

Comment: @abarnert, it's in the first part of the post, in the `SecondHandler`, which overrides http get. It gets fired off when regexp is matched from url.

Comment: I can see where it's defined, but how does it get called? "when regexp is matched from url" isn't enough; what's the stack trace?

Comment: I was hoping it would be a bit less generic than that… Anyway, I'll have to install Tornado 2.4 for Python 2.7 before I can look any further, which might not happen until Monday. Sorry; hope someone else can help before then.

Comment: Looking at the original error message you posted, it seemed that the error was obvious. But the traceback gives the opposite error! The first says "exactly 1 argument (2 given)" but the second says "exactly 2 arguments (1 given)". Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought at first that the problem was quite simple, but then you posted a traceback contradicting the original error message. However, I think the problem is still pretty straightforward, assuming that the *traceback* error is the correct one. Recall that this:

```
@decorator
def foo(x):
    return x + 1
```

Is simply syntactic sugar for this:

```
def foo(x):
    return x + 1
foo = oauth_machine.auth(foo)
```

So when you use `@oauth_machine.auth` on `get`, it's passed via a closure into `inner` as `fn`.

```
def auth(fn):
    def inner(self):
        res = get_user_by_credentials(self, fn, callback=done_auth)
    return inner
```

It's then passed into `get_user_by_credentials`, again as `fn`, which in turn produces another closure, which passes `fn` to `callback`.

```
def get_user_by_credentials(self, fn, callback):

    def onFetchUserCredentials(result, error):
        self.user = result
        callback(self, fn)
```

`callback` was defined as `done_auth` back in `inner`, so that menas that `fn` (i.e. the original `get`) is passed there, and then called on `result`:

```
def done_auth(result, fn):
    return fn(result)
```

But `fn` (i.e. `get`) takes two arguments. You pass it only one, causing an error.

Comment: hey, thanks for the dissection! I got it working in the meantime (updated the code), you're absolutely right - the get() gets fired off after it went through the decorator, but done_auth() was missing a param. I had to bounce it from closure to closure. Cheers!